# how to concatenate multidimensional array into one array?

Tags: python

I have a multi dimensional array of arrays like:

```
A = [array([[0]]),(array([[145]],array([[0]],array([[0]]),(array([[51],[9]]),array([[126],[26]]), array([[17],[0]])]
```

I need to put all the elements of all array into 1 array and then sort them. How can I do that so that in the end I get sth like this:

```
A2 = [0,0,0,0,9,17,26,51,126,145]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are these numpy arrays?

Comment: your brackets don't close, presumably you want `np.ravel`